# Bootstrap columns not working with masonry after window resize

Tags: bootstrap-4, masonry

I have built a review page and displayed the reviews using masonry.

The reviews on each side are `<div col-sm-12 col-md-6>` columns. However, when I try to resize the window to below 767px width, the bootstrap columns are still taking half of the screen size (remain as `col-md-6`). The weird thing is, when I go into Chrome browser's console and toggle the [device toolbar](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/imgs/device-mode-initial-view.png), the columns will be working perfectly. Any reason why it works when I view it via chrome's device toolbar but not when I resize the window manually?

Here is the js for masonry

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var masonryOptions = {
        columnWidth: '.card',
        itemSelector: '.grid-item',
        percentPosition: true,
        horizontalOrder: true
    };

    // initializes masonry
    var $grid = $('.grid').masonry( masonryOptions );
    var isActive = true;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that you have a css style near to the end of your compiled *template_4.css* file that sets the with of your `.card` items to 50% at all breakpoints. The style in question is `body.template4reviews .reviews-section .card` and it is used in your css as below.

```
body.template4reviews .reviews-section .card {
    width: 50%;
}

/* Note the `max-device-width` */
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 768px) {
    body.template4reviews .reviews-section .card {
        width: 90%;
    }
}
```

Since you use `max-device-width` in the media query, this means that the width of the `.card` items will be 50% every time on devices that have screens (and not the viewport) wider than 768px. On the other hand, `.card`s will be 90% wide on mobile devices. Hence you see the correct layout in the Chrome device toolbar.

Note:

- [`max-device-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%40media/device-width) is the maximum width of the **rendering surface of the device**.
- [`max-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@viewport/max-width) CSS descriptor specifies the maximum width of the **viewport of a document**.

So I guess you might wanted to use the `max-width` descriptor instead, like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    body.template4reviews .reviews-section .card {
        width: 90%;
    }
}
```